# Using Remote event receiver on list item adding create SPGroup in Autohosted App

Tags: 2013, autohosted, remote-event-receiver

I am trying to create remote event receiver on the list which is created in my app. I want to create SharePoint group when I add item in the list.
I have questions like:

1. Is it possible to create group in `AppWeb`? Though the event receiver of my list will create `ClientContext` of `appweb` URL.
2. If above is not possible then how can I get the `HostWeb` URL from the `ClientContext` which is created for the `appweb`?
3. Is there any other way to create `ClientContext` for the `hostweb` URL from the Remote event receiver created for the list in my app web?

Thank you in advance...!

Answer (score 1):

Groups are always created at the root level. An `appweb` is a subsite, so you cannot create groups inside it. However, you can create groups in `Hostweb` root site by creating a client context object of `HostWeb` in case you use APP Event Receiver.

```
using (ClientContext clientContext = TokenHelper.CreateAppEventClientContext(properties, false))
```

You need to pass the second parameter as `false` in `TokenHelper.reateAppEventClientContext`. You can get host web url in Remote event receiver using query string. 
`hostUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);`

Finally you need to give the app `Full Control` permissions on the Host web. Follwing code can be used to create groups:

```
private void CreateGroup(GroupCollection collGroup, string groupName, Web oWebsite, ClientContext clientContext)
{
    Group grp = collGroup.Where(g => g.Title == groupName).FirstOrDefault();
    if (grp == null)
    {
        GroupCreationInformation groupCreationInfo = new GroupCreationInformation();
        groupCreationInfo.Title = groupName;
        groupCreationInfo.Description = "Description of " + groupName;
        Group oGroup = oWebsite.SiteGroups.Add(groupCreationInfo);
        RoleDefinitionBindingCollection collRoleDefinitionBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
        RoleDefinition oRoleDefinition = oWebsite.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Contributor);
        collRoleDefinitionBinding.Add(oRoleDefinition);
        oWebsite.RoleAssignments.Add(oGroup, collRoleDefinitionBinding);
        clientContext.Load(oGroup, group => group.Title);
        clientContext.Load(oRoleDefinition, role => role.Name);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    }
}
```

For more information please see my blog. Here I create groups in APP Event Receiver http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.com/2014/02/sharepoint-2013-app-event-receivers.html

Comment: Yes but when I have added my list in my app. So it will create Event receiver for app web. And in that it will not give the option for useAppWeb = true or false.

Comment: That is why I also mentioned how to get Host web url `hostUrl = new Uri(Request.QueryString["SPHostUrl"]);`

Comment: Yes you have mentioned this code but how can I get Request from the cs page of the Event Receiver?

Answer (score 0):

As shown here: [Remote Event Receiver on host web](http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2014/07/remote-event-receivers-on-host-web-ClientContext.html)

You can use:

```
            // Workaround for getting client context. If not used, users are not able to create sites.
            string webUrl = properties.ItemEventProperties.WebUrl;

            Uri webUri = new Uri(webUrl);

            string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(webUri);

            string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, webUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
            using (var clientContext = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(webUrl, accessToken))
            {

            }
```