# Access Root Site List from Sub site using Remote Event Receiver in SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, sub-site, access-denied, remote-event-receiver

I am trying to access the Root site list using the sub site client context. But when I try to execute the `clientcontext` it gives Access Denied error.

I tried to create new `clientcontext` by passing the `accessToken` as well but no success. (Referred: [This](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94513/using-remote-event-receiver-on-list-item-adding-create-spgroup-in-autohosted-app))

Below is the code:

```
clientContext.Load(clientContext.Site);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
string siteUrl = clientContext.Site.Url;
Uri webUri = new Uri(siteUrl);
string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(webUri);
string accessToken = TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal, webUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;
using (var cc = TokenHelper.GetClientContextWithAccessToken(siteUrl, accessToken))
{
    cc.Load(cc.Web);
    cc.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Here, `clientContext` is the context of Sub-Site and cc is the context of Root site.

How can I access the cc using `clientContext`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution!!

We can access the Root site lists from subsite using below.

```
clientContext.Site.RootWeb.Lists
```

No need to create a new context of the Root site.